SwiftUI List row is selected instead of focusing the TextField
Problem

I have a List with selection binding, a custom rowView with two TextField in it.
When I click the text field, the list row is getting selected instead of the text field getting focused.
I'm targeting macOS 12.

Reproducible Example
struct DemoView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: DemoModel

    var body: some View {
        List(selection: self.$model.selectedRows) {
            DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: self.$model.isExpanded, content: {
                ForEach(self.model.models) { rowModel in
                    RowView(rowModel: rowModel)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .swipeActions {
                            Button("Swipe") {
                            }
                        }
                }
                .onMove { fromIndices, toIndex in
                    self.model.models.move(fromOffsets: fromIndices, toOffset: toIndex)
                }
            }, label: {
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("Title")
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Add row", systemImage: "plus") {
                        let rowModel = RowModel()
                        self.model.models.append(rowModel)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

class DemoModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var models: [RowModel]
    @Published var isExpanded: Bool
    @Published var selectedRows: Set<UUID>

    init() {
        let one = RowModel()
        let two = RowModel()
        self.models = [one, two]
        self.isExpanded = true
        self.selectedRows = Set()
    }
}

enum CustomFocusState {
    case textFieldOne, textFieldTwo
}

struct RowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var rowModel: RowModel
    @FocusState var focuseState: CustomFocusState?

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Enter text", text: self.$rowModel.text)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .padding()
                .focusable()
                .focused($focuseState, equals: .textFieldOne)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.focuseState = .textFieldOne
                    print("tapped textFieldOne")
                }
            TextField("Enter text", text: self.$rowModel.text2)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .padding()
                .focusable()
                .focused($focuseState, equals: .textFieldTwo)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.focuseState = .textFieldTwo
                    print("tapped textFieldTwo")
                }
        }
    }
}

class RowModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var text: String
    @Published var text2: String
    var id: UUID

    init() {
        self.text = ""
        self.text2 = ""
        self.id = UUID()
    }
}

extension RowModel: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: RowModel, rhs: RowModel) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.id)
    }
}

Current behaviour

On first click the row is getting selected, only on the second click the textfield is getting focused

Expected behaviour

If the click is on the textfield, then the textfield should get focused
If the click is on the row apart from the textfield, the row should get selected

EDIT

Strangely If I remove the .onMove modifier, the row selection and the TextField focus seems to work but I'm not sure why?
Maybe there's a bug in how list handles row selection and input field focus within the row? Please correct me If I'm wrong.


As opposed you probably want to achieve, your list has just one row: it's the DisclosureGroup. I guess, you want something different – but I don't know what exactly (a disclosure group enclosing the list?). Also,  it seems, one cannot have a Button in a DisclosureGroup's label. As you can see, the button behaves irregularly - it's the whole label which acts as a button. Move the Add feature to a toolbar or to the navigation bar. Some minor other things: you do not need to set the focus explicitly via tabGesture, but you may observe changes, using a onChange(on: focusState) modifier.

I need to correct myself: if you enclose the DisclosureGroup into the List content, we get the DisclosureGroup's label on the first row, and all other rows follows and we can close and open the rows. I observed no other  irregularities with the edit fields, though. They worked as expected. You can even collapse the group when a field has the focus (which will be removed and the keyboard disappears). When you can fix the "Add" button, it should work.

In addition: it seems, a DisclosureGroup cannot have a List as content. When we try this, the list items will not be rendered. It seems, the List should enclose the DisclosureGroup - which results in what we get.

The above is just an example to showcase the behaviour.
When you click within the region of the TextField, didn't the list row get
selected? For me this is the behaviour.
Did you try selecting the TextField from within the same row and from different rows?

I removed the onTabGesture modifier and it worked as one would expect: getting keyboard visible, moving focus, selecting the cell, closing the group. Note that the focusState variable will be set automatically (you can set it programmatically, to control the focus, too though). Note, that this does not fix the issues with your models (see @malhal's answer).

Change RowModel to a struct. It doesn't make sense for classes to be identified by id, since they already are identified by their pointer, so change it to a struct. @Published needs to be an array of model structs to work anyway.
Also, remove selection from the model store object. If you think about it you might want the model data to be presented in different ways all which might need their own selection so selection should be @State instead.

If I change the RowModel to struct, then I will not be able to conform to ObservableObject.
It needs to be a class to be able to observe the properties and update the UI for RowView
What do you mean by @Published needs to be an array of structs to work?

You only need one ObservableObject. If you make RowModel a struct then when it changes, an array of RowModel in @Published will send when a property of RowModel changes. It doesn't send if the array is of objects and a property of object is changed.

Try removing .focusable() from the text field.

After removing focusable(), it is working for me.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
